Is there a website similar to Wikipedia which I can use only for me for personal purpose?
I am looking for a website which is
I can add, edit, and delete my data like Wikipedia,
but my data can be modified only by me and can be shown only to me,
and hosted by someone else in the public.
It does not matter whether it is free or paid, of course, free is preferred.
Is there such a web service?

WIkipedia and WIkidata offer data dumps with their content. MediaWiki Software must be installed separately. I guess that's quite a bit of work, making your own copy of Wikipedia.

The closest you'll get to Wikipedia is by self-hosting MediaWiki either locally or if you need it online then with e.g. restricted viewing or HTTP auth to block unwanted guests.

You should look at TiddlyWiki.  From their website:  "TiddlyWiki lets you choose where to keep your data, guaranteeing that in the decades to come you will still be able to use the notes you take today".
